# Receiving a 404 error on my well-written (I think) express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My understanding is I have the server set-up correctly. I have no errors related to imports or missing libraries. I'm using cors as this is for development. I've tried commenting out the bodyparser with the same 404 error.

[image]

But, I do get a 204 response on the server's log:

[image]

According to [httpstatuses.com](https://httpstatuses.com/204) this means, "The server has successfully fulfilled [some] request..."

```js
// main server file
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(cors());

require("./api").default(app)

app.listen(API_PORT, () => console.log(`LISTENING ON PORT ${API_PORT}`));
```

```js
// api's index.js file
export default function (app) {
    app.use("/api/users", require("./user"))
}
```

```js
// ./user file with router
let router = new Router()

router.post("/", controller.add_edit_user) // api/users/

module.exports = router
```

```js
// controller function
export function add_edit_user(req, res) {

    console.log(req);
}
```

At this point, I just want to see the req logged in the console.

Comment: try ```/api/api/users```

Comment: Nothing is logged right now and only the 404 errors on the client and the server logs. The client says 404, so as far as it seems, that function isn't even running.

Comment: Have you tried going to `/api/users` as that is what you have setup for the `use()` call and your `post()` is just `/` so the endpoint url would be `/api/users` not `/users`

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi Wow! That did it. It logged the request! I must have my routing to my api all screwy. I got to experiment with this. Thanks so much. (Will approve, if you write this as an answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// api's index.js file
export default function (app) {
    app.use("/users", require("./user")) // You need to change the route to "/users"
}
```

Comment: @Gabriel-Kunkel the key point is when you add a middleware to upper section it will affects all sub routes. So you can control V1,V2,Vn API structures of your app clean and without headache.

Answer (score 3):

I have 3+ years with Express mate and I have never seen that kind of structuring it.
So, here's how it will surely work.

```js
index.js

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const logger = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const router = require("./router");

app.use('/', router);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(cors());


const API_PORT = 3000;

app.listen(API_PORT, () => console.log(`LISTENING ON PORT ${API_PORT}`));
```

```js
router.js

const { Router } = require("express");
const router = Router();
const handler = require("./handler");

router.post('/api/users', handler.addEditUser);

module.exports = router;
```

```js
handler.js

exports.addEditUser = async (req, reply) => {

  // your code
}
```

Comment: And you can't fully control middle-wares in grouped routes in scalable apps.

Comment: Sure thing @GabrielKunkel !